# IEnumerable<XElement> of a list of temperatures from an xml

Tags: c#, linq

I can't access the temperature node. I would have a list of temperature in a `IEnumerable<XElement>`.

This is the code for now the result of `IEnumerable<XElement>` is 0

```
XElement xml = XElement.Load("http://dati.meteotrentino.it/service.asmx/ultimiDatiStazione?codice=T0408");

IEnumerable<XElement> temperature = xml.Elements("temperature");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take the xml namespace (`xmlns="http://www.meteotrentino.it/"`) into consideration

```
XElement xml = XElement.Load("http://dati.meteotrentino.it/service.asmx/ultimiDatiStazione?codice=T0408");

XNamespace ns = "http://www.meteotrentino.it/";
IEnumerable<XElement> temperature = xml.Elements(ns + "temperature");
var temperatura_aria = temperature.Descendants(ns + "temperatura_aria");
```

So I would do it this way:

```
XElement xml = XElement.Load("http://dati.meteotrentino.it/service.asmx/ultimiDatiStazione?codice=T0408");
XNamespace ns = "http://www.meteotrentino.it/";

var temperatura_aria = xml.Descendants(ns + "temperatura_aria")
                            .Select(x => new
                            {
                                Time = (DateTime)x.Element(ns+ "data"),
                                Temp = (decimal)x.Element(ns + "temperatura"),
                            })
                            .ToList();
```